# which notepad++ syntax highlighting style is applying these colors?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, notepad++

Screenshot: [image: notepad++ syntax highlighting screenshot]

Using notepad++ v6.3.2 and editing an html file, Notepad++ is using strange colors to highlight the code. Problem is, i can't find those color values in any section of the theme (Global Styles or HTML or C#). The mysterious green color code is: #707312 and it's not in my modified twightlight.xml. Also, i don't use "transparency" anywhere either, so it's not a variation of some other color.

I use a custom Twilight.xml theme which is located here:
C:\Program Files\Notepad++\themes\twighlight.xml

I'd be happy to share that file, but i don't know how to do that. Can someone please tell me what Notepad++ "style" is highlighting that code selection?

thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

After weeks of fighting this issue, i found the answer. To anyone using Notepad++ and are struggling with seeing weird syntax highlighting when editing HTML or XML files, see here:

https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331753/thread/696b4764/

1. There may be duplicate values in the theme xml file. You have to remove the duplicates. Specifically, "Find Mark Style" is the culprit.
2. Open your theme, go to "Global Styles" and remove any dupes (C:\Program Files\Notepad++\themes"yourtheme".xml)
   Note: 2021 ... this file may be called stylers.model.xml
3. Update the color that controls this background highlighting.
4. Uncheck "Highlight Tag Attributes" found here:
   Settings -> Preferences -> Highlight Matching Tags -> [ ] Highlight Tag Attributes
5. select your new tag highlighting color:
6. Settings -> Style Configurator -> Global Styles -> Tags Match Highlighting (set background to the color you wish)

3b. Alternatively, if you don't see "Tags Match Highlighting", it may be "MISC" (thanks to GPPK below)

This should prevent the weird yellow background from showing up when you edit files that have tags (e.g. HTML, XML, etc.)

Comment: +1 This has annoyed me for a little over a year but I couldn't find a solution, thank you.

Comment: You are my hero. There are not enough +1s for this in the world

Comment: Because I can't edit this question, the "Highlight matching tags" option is now in the MISC. tab

Comment: This put me on the right track to copy attribute highlight settings from another theme to get rid of that horrible rgb(125,125,25)

Answer (score 8):

An additional information to change strange color at HTML/XML attribute,

- Settings -> Style Configurator -> Global Styles -> Tags attribute (see background color)

Comment: I like this better. Then you can still have the highlighting, but it's not that harsh yellow/green color. I just made it the same color as the background, but made the `Lum` a little bit lighter.

Comment: Please note that, from what i remember (i'm the OP) the problem was a duplicate row which was preventing this simple solution from working. The duplicate row was the problem. Just setting the Tags attribute didn't work originally, but it may work in newer releases.